# How to compare image using AShot in selenium (Java)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using this code:

```java
    package wayPoint;
    
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    
    import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.AShot;
    import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot;
    import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.comparison.ImageDiff;
    import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.comparison.ImageDiffer;
    import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.shooting.ShootingStrategies;
    
    
    public class imageCompare {
        @Test
        public void ImageComparison() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
              //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","write here path of chromedriver exe file");
            DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
            dc.setCapability("marionette", false);
            //FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
            WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(dc);
            
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(150,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         
            driver.get("URL");
            driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys("userName");
            driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys("password");
            driver.findElement(By.name("Submit")).click();
            driver.navigate().to("URL2");
            
            WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OL_Icon_618_innerImage']"));
            
            System.out.println("value= "+webElement);
            
            
            BufferedImage expectedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/neha/neha/screenshotsByCode/mm_20_red.png"));
            
            System.out.println("\n expectedImage= "+expectedImage );
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            
            Screenshot scrnshot = new AShot().takeScreenshot(driver, webElement);
            
            ImageIO.write(scrnshot.getImage(),"PNG", new File("/home/neha/neha/screenshotsByCode/image.png"));
            
            BufferedImage actualImage = scrnshot.getImage();
            
            ImageDiffer imgDiff = new ImageDiffer();
            
            ImageDiff diff = imgDiff.makeDiff(expectedImage,actualImage);
            
            System.out.println("finally");
            Assert.assertTrue(diff.equals(diff), "Images are Same");
        }
    
    }
```

But I get the following exception:

```java
    FAILED: ImageComparison
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: el.offset is not a function
      (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.96)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 4.4.0-31-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 13 milliseconds
    Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '2aa21c1', time: '2016-08-02 14:59:43 -0700'
    System info: host: 'neha', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-31-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac), userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.5mBoy6}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.96, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
```

Comment: I met with the same problem. org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: el.offset is not a function

Comment: I faced the same problem. Somebody know how to resolve it?